# Segmentation fault in C++ thread

Tags: c++, pthreads, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to set up a basic threaded class in C++, but I'm getting a seg fault when I try to create a thread. Here's what GDB reports:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401b68 in StartThread (pFunction=
    0x401ad2 <FindPrimesThread(void*)>, pLimit=5000000) at Thread.cpp:35
35          state->mLimit = pLimit;
```

when I try to call it like this:

```
ThreadState *primesState = StartThread(FindPrimesThread, 5000000);
```

Here's my code:

Thread.hpp

```
#ifndef THREAD_HPP
#define THREAD_HPP

#include <pthread.h>
#include "Types.hpp"

typedef struct {
    ulong       mLimit;     // Upper limit of numbers to test 
    int         mStarted;   // True if the thread started successfully
    int         mExitCode;  // Thread exit code
    pthread_t   mThreadId;  // Thread ID
} ThreadState;

// Defines a type named ThreadFunction which is a pointer to a function with void * as the parameter and
// void * as the return value.
typedef void *(*ThreadFunction)(void *);

ThreadState *StartThread
    (
    ThreadFunction const pFunction,  // Pointer to the thread function
    ulong const          pLimit      // Upper limit of numbers to test
    );

#endif
```

Thread.cpp

```
#include "Amicable.hpp"
#include "Keith.hpp"
#include "Main.hpp"
#include "Prime.hpp"
#include "Thread.hpp"

ThreadState *StartThread
    (
    ThreadFunction const pFunction,  // Pointer to the thread function
    ulong const          pLimit      // Upper limit of numbers to test
    ) {
        ThreadState *state;
        state->mLimit = pLimit;
        pthread_t threadId;
        state->mStarted = pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, pFunction, (void *)state);
        if(state->mStarted == 0){
            state->mThreadId = threadId;
        }
        return state;
    }
```

Any idea on what's going wrong here?

Comment: You could make your life **much** easier if you used [boost threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread.html) or [c++11 threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Threading_facilities)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ThreadState *state;
state->mLimit = pLimit;
```

You are writing to memory you haven't allocated

Comment: +1 Indeed. One must understand pointers before going anywhere *near* threads.

Comment: @GregHewgill: At least in C++. Concurrent Pascal (for one example) would be a slightly different story (even though normal Pascal has pointers, Concurrent Pascal eliminated them, at least if I recall correctly).

Comment: Yep! I totally overlooked that. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3):

You have an uninitialized pointer in ThreadState. On line 35, you create a pointer to a ThreadState, but you never assign that pointer to point to any ThreadState object.

Remember, a pointer is just a memory address. "ThreadState*" just means, "this is a memory address, and we can interpret the data in memory at the address I hold to be a ThreadState object."

Perhaps you meant to do "ThreadState *state = new ThreadState();"? Don't forget, someone will need to go and delete that ThreadState object when they're done using it so as not to leak memory!

Comment: That's it! I knew I was overlooking something, I've been working on this so long I overlooked that pointer.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :) That's why there's SO, to help us with the things we're too bleary-eyed to notice.

Comment: "You have a null-pointer in ThreadState" - the variable is simply *uninitialised* and in general could be NULL or any other value.